# Set custom format for FORMAT() function

Tags: mysql, mariadb, locale, number-formatting

I was wondering if there is any way to use custom formats when using the FORMAT function.
Something like:

```
SELECT FORMAT(money,"##.###,00") FROM account
```

or any other way to format values directly inside the query.

This is actually to find a workaround for a "wrong" number format for the it_IT locale (at least in our case), which results as #####,00 instead of ##.###,00 .
This looks like a known bug as stated in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73436 .

Comment: Simply specify needed locale. `SELECT FORMAT(money, 2, 'de-DE') FROM account`

Comment: @Rastafan, I see what you mean. Please create a [MariaDB bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) as it clearly doesn't match [ICU Locale Italian](https://www.localeplanet.com/icu/it-IT/index.html). Also writing a fix against the [source](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.6/sql/sql_locale.cc) should be pretty easy.